# C# debugging across dlls

Tags: c#, debugging, dll

I have a project which has a calling structure similar to this:

- main project/application

  my library code

  someone else's library code

  my library code

Everything's written in C#, and I have access to 'someone else's library code'.  Their code is not included in my project, because it's open source and not my code.  I can make debug versions of all the libraries, and I've done so.

That 'someone else's library code (SELC, I guess?) is throwing an exception in a heisen-bug kind of way, and I'm trying to track it down and maybe submit a bugfix to the project maintainer.  Problem is, my debugging stack is stopping at my library code, and lists the SELC as 'external' and I can't debug into it.  I've copied the pdb files as well as the debug version of the library into the debug directory of my application, and still no luck; I can't seem to debug into their code, and I can't step into it at all.

Once upon a time, back in vs6 days, I could do this-- have two different projects open at the same time in two different environments, and have the debugger trace across dll boundaries from one project into another.  I'd assume that functionality remains, because it's just so dang useful.

Any suggestions?

I've looked for this answer but not found it, so if this is a dupe, just let me know where to look.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you have "Just My Code" turned on in Visual Studio's debugging options?

Comment: It doesn't seem to matter.  I still can't step into their code.

Comment: Ah, ok, I had to do it for both projects.  This got it.  Thanks!

Comment: Should it be checked, or unchecked? ... I have set it to unchecked in both but it still doesnt seem to work ...

Answer (score 0):

If you have the sources (as i read from you), you can make an **project** with their source code, and then add the project to your **solution**.
In visual studio the project in .csproj file , and solutions in .sln file.

Comment: Yeah, as I said, I don't want to do that, because it's not my source.  I want to keep the sources distinct from one another.  I understand that I might not be able to do so, but still-- in vc6 I could do this kind of thing.